# FB scope publish_actions not asking

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

in our apps we have the option to share activity on Facebook after which the users get a small reward. In recent days this feature has stopped working for some of our users because we didn't get "post_id" from your side which we need to determine if the user should get a reward.

We found out that this happens when the user hasn't given us the "publish_actions" right. Therefore we have added a check for this right and we try to request it this way:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions/publish_actions', function(response) {
  // pokud mame pravo na zverejneni obsahu hned postujeme
  if (response.data && response.data[0] && response.data[0]['status'] === 'granted') {
    postShareReport();
  } else {
    // pokud nemame, tak si zkusime vyzadat pravo
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         // pokud nam ho dal, tak postujeme
         if(response.authResponse.grantedScopes && response.authResponse.grantedScopes.indexOf('publish_actions') !== -1) {
            postShareReport();
         }
       }                  
     }, {scope: "email,publish_actions",return_scopes: true, auth_type: 'rerequest'});          
  }
});
```

However, here we encountered another problem. The publish_actions right is not requested from some users even though they haven't given us this right. The login process does go through, however. The user doesn't receive the window with the option to give us this right.

Thank you
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Most permissions need to get reviewed by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Without review, `publish_actions` only works for users with a role in the App. Ohter users don´t get asked for the permission in the authorization process.

Btw, not getting a Post ID or information if the user really shared something is intentional, because rewarding the user in any way for sharing is not allowed. You need to read the platform policy before creating any App, that rule is in there since years:

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/